# Install R 3.2.2 for Mac OSX 10.7.5

Tags: r, macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, osx-snow-leopard

It seems that CRAN will not provide binaries for 3.2.2 for OSX 10.6-10.8. The 3.2.1 binary is termed now legary binary. 
Is there any way to get R 3.2.2 for a machine running 10.7.5 and has no option to upgrade past this OSX?

Comment: This might help: http://r.research.att.com

Comment: What is this page? Is this something official/reliable/trusted? Security concerns? What is the difference between the 2 files of each build?

Comment: Please read https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/